# Pandas: how to set date format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: python, pandas, date, format

If I have a dataframe created from a csv file containing a column with date values (11.01.2023) how can I transform the column into a date format like `dd/mm/yyyy` (day 2 characters, month 2 characters, years 4 characters)?
Thank you all

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '11.01.2023 ', 1: '22.01.2023', 2: '08.02.2023' }, 
                  'Price':{0:123, 1:456, 2:789}})
df
```

Comment: Simply `df['Date'].str.replace('.', '/', regex=False)` or `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I did
df['Date'].str.replace('.', '/', regex=False)
and the dataframe results as at the beginning

Comment: Did you assign? `df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace('.', '/', regex=False)`

Comment: Yes. I also tried with the command
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace('.', '/', regex=False)
But if I check the properties: df.info() I get the column Date is defined as "object" while I thought it should be of type
"datetime64[ns]". Is that correct?

Comment: Then provide a reproducible example, there is no issue with your current one.

Comment: HI. These are the steps I take :

Comment: how can i attach a small sample file?

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible example as [edit] to your question: `df.head().to_dict('list')`

Comment: import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '11.01.2023 ', 1: '22.01.2023', 2: '08.02.2023' }, 
                  'Price':{0:123, 1:456, 2:789}})