# Python Pandas: how to set date format dd/mm/yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy and dtypes = datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, object, format

If I have a dataframe created from a csv file containing a column with date values (11.01.2023) how can I transform the column into a date format like dd/mm/yyyy (day 2 characters, month 2 characters, years 4 characters) or like dd.mm.yyyy? Thank you all

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '11.01.2023 ', 1: '22.01.2023', 2: '08.02.2023' }, 
                  'Price':{0:123, 1:456, 2:789}})
df
```

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '11.01.2023 ', 1: '22.01.2023', 2: '08.02.2023' }, 
                  'Price':{0:123, 1:456, 2:789}})

df['Date'].str.replace('.', '/', regex=False)
print(df.dtypes)    #    The Date column is object format


df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True) 
print(df.dtypes)    #   The Date column is format datetime64[ns]
print('df', df)     #   The date column is of the type yyyy-mm-dd
```

At this point how should I do to transform the Date column into a "dd/mm/yyyy"
or "dd.mm.yyyy" format **and dtypes =datetime64** ?

See Image:

[image]

thank you all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: how to set date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75888459/pandas-how-to-set-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: @rorshan Not quietly, I think op wants to change the display format of `dtypes =datetime64`.

Comment: No. I want to change the format fom object to datetime64. So I can do operations with dates

Answer (score 1):

It is a deceptively hard question to answer. It depends on your use case.
If you are using pandas in a notebook environment, then you should use a styler. Here's a short example explaining how it works:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
from IPython.display import display

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '11.01.2023 ', 1: '22.01.2023', 2: '08.02.2023' }, 
                  'Price':{0:123, 1:456, 2:789}})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df_styler = df.style.format({'Date': lambda t: t.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")})
print(df.dtypes) # dtypes are not changed

print(df_styler) # printing a styler doesn't show the dataframe
print(df) # printing a dataframe this way does not involve the styler

display(df_styler) # this is how to render a dataframe with a styler

df['Date'] = df['Date'] + timedelta(days=5)

# the styler doesn't need to be remade if df changes
display(df_styler)

# in a notebook environment having a `df_styler` as the last
# command is equivalent to `display(df_styler)`
df_styler
```

If you're not using a notebook environment, you can use `df_styler.to_html()` to get a formatted table in HTML.

if you are not in a notebook environment and/or want to use `print(df)` instead of rendering the dataframe as an HTML object, there is no good solution that I know of. What I would probably do in that case is write my own `print_df` function which would replace the `Date` column on the fly with a string column formatted with `strftime` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strftime function to format the datetime column into a specific string format. Use the . separator by using the %d.%m.%Y format string.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '11.01.2023 ', 1: '22.01.2023', 2: '08.02.2023' },
                   'Price':{0:123, 1:456, 2:789}})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

# Format the datetime column into "dd.mm.yyyy" format
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

print(df.dtypes)
print(df)
```

Try this.
Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-dt-strftime/

Comment: With this answer the `Date` column now has an `object` dtype because the column contains strings and not `datetime` objects

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The print(df.dtypes) command returns object for the Date column.
At this point, how can I do mathematical operations such as, for example, calculate the number of days between a date and the previous date or find the date that is obtained by adding 20 days to the Date column?

Comment: Convert it to a datetime type using pd.to_datetime() again and assign it back to the Date column.                                                                                                         
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') Please let me if this solves your need